# Using IF in an HREF while passing a variable and incrementing my variable if the href button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `href` inside my navigation bar (bootstrap) and I declared a variable "purchases" I also have another `href` in which when it is clicked, the value of purchases which should be in my first href should also change. The problem is I don't know how to put a variable inside the `href` and I'm not sure if I used the correct procedure to increment.

```
<li>
    <a href="#"> Number of Purhaces</a>
</li>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var purchases = 0;
</script>

<a href="#" id=clickme class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button">BUY!</a>

<script>
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function() {
purchase++;
}
</script>
```

Comment: your id should be written as id="clickme"

Comment: purchase++ should be purchases++

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function() {
purchase++;
//change your href
document.getElementById('clickme').href = "bla";
}
</script>
```

'bla' could start with 'http://' or with '#' (you probably need the latter). In case you need to alter href of the first link, just assign an id to it and use the same approach.

I hope this helps.